# Using "in" for describing people's outfits

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between the following sentences?

> There was a woman **in** red earrings.
>
> There was a woman **with** red earrings.
>
> There was a woman **with wearing** red earrings.

I understand that "in" can use with clothes like "a man in the grey suit.", but I'm not sure I can use "in" with other things like earrings and necklaces, etc.

What is the difference between the highlighted sentences, and can I use *in* with items of jewelry such as earrings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I would use "in" for larger items of clothing that clearly contain significant parts of the body (shirt, pants; even hats, shoes, and gloves) and "with" for smaller accessories (including earrings and necklaces). "Wearing" can be used for both, but has a more formal/stuffy tone. "With wearing" is never correct -- use one or the other.

Of course there are many nuances; for example all of these are idiomatic:

> There was a woman with a red dress (but see the comment below)
>
> There was a woman wearing a red dress
>
> There was a woman in a red dress
>
> There was a woman wearing red
>
> There was a woman in red

but have increasingly strong connotations about how distinctive the red dress was.

Comment: This is a good answer, and I've upvoted! :) But I would caution readers that your first example is a bit ambiguous. I would read "...with a red dress" to mean that the woman is *holding* a red dress, not wearing it. I suppose the interpretation of her wearing it is possible, but I don't think it is likely. I'd like this answer better if the first example were removed, because the rest are excellent!